# Pixi is not changing position when click on sprite

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixi.js

I was trying to create a sample pixi application. Where I had an image, when user clicks on the image, it should move its position.

```
var canvasWidth = window.innerWidth;
var canvasHight = window.innerHeight

var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(canvasWidth, canvasHight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
var stage = new PIXI.Container();

PIXI.loader
    .add('images/sample.png')
    .add('images/background.jpg')
    .load(setup);

function setup() {
    var backGround = new PIXI.Sprite(
        PIXI.loader.resources["images/background.jpg"].texture);
    var steve = new PIXI.Sprite(
        PIXI.loader.resources["images/sample.png"].texture);
    backGround.hieght = canvasHight;
    backGround.width = canvasWidth;
    setPropertiesToSteve(steve);
    stage.addChild(backGround);
    stage.addChild(steve);
    renderer.render(stage);
}

// Function just to set properties for steve
function setPropertiesToSteve(steve) {
    steve.interactive = true;
    steve.position.x = canvasWidth/2;
    steve.position.x = canvasWidth/4;
    steve.on('pointerdown',function(){
        steve.position.x = steve.position.x + 10;
    });
}
```

But when I click on the object nothing happening. I am very much new to pixijs.SO don't know how to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to render the stage again :) 
Take a look at the official Pixi examples https://pixijs.github.io/examples/

They use the PIXI.Application class which sets up common things like a ticker that automatically re renders your stage

Comment: Thanks themoonart.   I was doing my first pixi application. When I re render the stage it worked. :)